# Is there a way to properly implement multi-threading when showing a MessageBox in C#?

Tags: c#

I am currently fixing up a C#-based Remote Access Tool (for demonstration purposes), and wish to implement multi-threading for the MessageBox function.

I also have slight C# experience, so this'll be a bit awkward to spit out.

This MessageBox spawning code is targeted for .NET FW v4.6.1, and is a standard Windows Application, without a console window. I have already tried (out of sheer cluelessness) to set the Apartment type to an MTA.

```cs
using System.Threading;
var t = new Thread(() => MessageBox.Show(text, "placeholder",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1,
                MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly));
            t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            t.Start();
```

The expected output of this when ran in succession is multiple MessageBoxes, but the outcome is that there is only one MessageBox, and the other MessageBoxes only appear when the initial (and consecutive) boxes are closed out of.

Comment: Message boxes are run by the UI thread, and unless they are really modeless dialog boxes they are modal which also means synchronous.  If you want multiple simultaneous updates a message box is the wrong UI element for that.  Try text windows on your form, or maybe a floating modeless window with multiple message areas instead

Answer (score 4):

> I wish to implement multi-threading for the MessageBox function.

Do not do so. This is a bad idea. User interface controls should be run from a dedicated UI thread.

> I also have slight C# experience

Writing a correct multi-threaded program with a user interface is an expert-level task; you should start by gaining much, much more C# experience, or hire someone who has the appropriate experience.

> I have already tried (out of sheer cluelessness) to set the Apartment type to an MTA.

Programming via desperately trying stuff and seeing what works is not a good technique for writing correct multi-threaded programs. Use good engineering practice: understand the system, and write code that deliberately and correctly manipulates the system. Program with confidence; if you do not have confidence, gain experience solving simpler problems until you do.

> The expected output of this when ran in succession is multiple MessageBoxes

That your expectation is completely opposite reality indicates that you do not have a correct mental concept of how message boxes work. Again, do not attempt to solve this problem until you have a correct understanding.

> the other MessageBoxes only appear when the initial (and consecutive) boxes are closed out of

That's correct. If you do not understand the difference between modal and modeless controls, **learn that difference before you continue to program user interfaces**.

> Is there a way to properly implement multi-threading when showing a MessageBox in C#?

You should not attempt to do so.

It sounds like you want multiple modeless dialogs. A better solution is to dedicate one specific thread to service the UI, and put all the modeless dialogs on that thread; **all calls to those controls from other threads must be marshalled to that apartment**.